# CKeditor autogrow plugin inside Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I'm using multiple CKeditors (latest version, 4.5.7) inside Bootstrap tabs. I want to add autogrow to the editors, so they always fit the content. I have the plugin installed and have this in my config:

```
config.autoGrow_minHeight = 500;
config.autoGrow_onStartup = true;
```

It works fine for the first (visible) editor, but when I click a tab the other editors are MASSIVE - thousands of pixels tall. As soon as I click in the editor it resizes to the correct size.

Here's a full demo: http://85.159.215.184/cke-grow/ - click Tab 2 to see the problem.

This may be a bug in CKeditor, but since their bug reporting site isn't working I'm asking here in case there is a simple fix or workaround. Any help?

Comment: FYI - works fine in firefox, see issue in chrome. Have you tried enabling editor manually when tabs are switched?

Comment: @charlietfl Actually in Firefox the editor stays the same size and does not expand to fit the content if it's longer. See updated demo.

Comment: problem is related to tab-content being hidden and therefore no dimensions available. Can change css from `display:none` to moving inactive content off screen and moving it back on screen when active. Same issue occurs with things like maps that need to calculate dimensions

Comment: OK thanks. Do you know how to manually call autogrow when switching tabs? In the same way when I click it recalculates the height. I don't see any info on the CKeditor site. (Feel free to post as an answer)

Comment: Try the css route first...will actually be the simplest and won't require any script changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution: automatically focusing the editor when the tab is switched.

```
// hook into Bootstrap's tab JS
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // get the ID of the textarea (I have IDs based on the tab pane ID)
    var paneId = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
    var textareaId = 'content-'+paneId;
    // get the CKEditor instance and focus it
    CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId].focus();
});
```